# PHP - What does "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"-Error means?

Tags: php

I wrote a simple crawler using Simple HTML Dom Parser to scrape some stuff.

It's a simple script only running with 1 process and nothing massive. But after some time it produces a `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"-error,` when I am running it in the shell.

When I run the script in the browser it says

```
"Error: The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.".
```

I have made sure to `unset()` every variable as soon as possible and also increased the `memory_limit` in `php.ini`, but still I get this error :/

Does someone know what it means and how to solve it?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault That would be a crash of PHP itself (or one of its extensions), rather than a fault in your code.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I always wanted a good reason to finally start with Java and stop using PHP :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski He should also know that the crash is most likely *because* of his code, even though it is the language's fault that it crashed instead of showing an error. Also Crayl: You will find Java is generally more difficult as a server-side script than PHP, so don't switch to if if you're looking for an easy fix.

Comment: @Dave Also interesting, thanks. Could also be caused by my code, because it got alot better since I have unset() all variables as soon they weren't needed anymore.

Comment: Bear in mind that there is often a different, separate, php.ini file for command-line PHP; are you sure you're changing the memory_limit in the right file? (Try dumping `ini_get('memory_limit');` in your script to double-check.) Also, if it's a memory leak that's causing the problem, which sounds the likeliest candidate, we'll need to see the script to know what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

I have this problem when a made a recursive loop by accident, so it runs out of memory. But the way it tells me is by making a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error!

So look a the code you most recently wrote and check if you made a error like this! My example was very simple (and stupid). I was just a little to fast to accept the autocomplete's suggestion :)

```
public function getAttendees()
{
    return $this->getAttendees();
}
```

Hope this can help someone in the future

Answer (score 2):

If anybody else has the same problem with Simple HTML Dom Parser: In this case the error was caused because of too long webpages. SHDP has a preconfigured "MAX_FILE_SIZE". You have to increase it in the source of `simple_html_dom.php`. See line:

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
```

Comment: If this was the solution to the problem, you should accept this answer; it's perfectly fine to answer your own questions here.

Answer (score 2):

I've had it because free HDD space in VM ended due to too much data in /tmp folder

Answer (score 1):

The 'core dumped' I think just means the program released the memory and exited.

A segmentation fault usually occurs when you try and access a part of memory that is not yours to use, or by deferencing an uninitialised or invalid pointer.

Could you be passing/using a bad handle or overrunning an array somewhere?

Comment: "core dumped" means the system produced a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) somewhere for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score -6):

I just has same issue.
I was doing

```
return $var;
```

Which caused the error. However returning

```
return [$var][0];
```

worked. I'm sure there is a good explanation for this but I don't know it.